# VS2015 restarts on exit

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I'm using Visual Studio 2015 CTP on Windows 8.1 x64 and I want to exit VS it restarts when I still have the vs-mda (android emulator) running.
It only restarts once, when I close the restarted vs2015 it will just exit normally.

Anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: I am seeing VS still running as a process after exit.

Comment: I was having the same issue lately. It turned out to be an extension that was causing this. I un-installed it and now it's working fine.